# kubernetes: How to download and upload image to internal network

Tags: kubernetes

Our customer uses internal network. We have k8s application, some yaml files need to download image from internet. I have a win10 computer and I could ssh internal server and access internet. How to download image and then upload to internal server?

Some image download site would be:

```
chenliujin/defaultbackend  (nginx-default-backend.yaml)
quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0
```

Comment: The best way - deploy local mirror for `Docker` repositories. For example, it could be `Artifactory` by JFrog.

Comment: @KonstantinVustin I would encourage you to make that an Answer, not a comment, so it can be upvoted as one and accepted as the answer to this problem

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel ok, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to download image and then upload to internal server?

The shortest path to success is

```
ssh the-machine-with-internet -- 'bash -ec \
  "docker pull quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0 ; \
   docker save quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0"' \
   | ssh the-machine-without-internet -- 'docker load'
```

You'll actually need to repeat that `ssh machine-without-internet -- docker load` bit for every Node in the cluster, otherwise they'll attempt to pull the image when they don't find it already in `docker images`, which brings us to ...

You are also free to actually cache the intermediate file, if you wish, as in:

```
ssh machine-with-internet -- 'bash -ec \
  "docker pull quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0 ; \
   docker save -o /some/directory/nginx-ingress-0.15.0.tar quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0"'
scp machine-with-internet /some/directory/nginx-ingress-0.15.0.tar /some/other/place
# and so forth, including only optionally running the first pull-and-save step
```

It is entirely possible to use an `initContainer:` in the PodSpec to implement any kind of pre-loading of docker images before the main Pod's containers attempt to start, but that's likely going to clutter your PodSpec unless it's pretty small and straightforward.

Having said all of that, as @KonstantinVustin already correctly said: having a local docker repository for mirroring the content will save you a ton of heartache

Answer (score 3):

The best way - deploy local mirror for `Docker` repositories. For example, it could be `Artifactory` by JFrog